# Construct an inscribed equilateral triangle - proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-construction

> Construct an equilateral triangle inscribed in a given circle.  Prove the construction using synthetic geometry only.

There are two standard constructions for this:

1. Find a $\pi/6$ angle via a right triangle (angle on the circle subtending the diameter) with one leg half the length of the diameter.  See e.g. [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/zZj5X6Fz) or [here](https://tasks.illustrativemathematics.org/content-standards/tasks/1557).
2. Inscribe a regular hexagon by using chords equal to the radius.  Then connect every other point.  See e.g. [here](https://daniellemarks.pbworks.com/w/file/fetch/110331919/Constructions%20CW%20C1.5.pdf) or [here](https://etc.usf.edu/clipart/49900/49948/49948_construction.htm).

Can we prove these constructions using synthetic geometry only (no trig)?

Comment: Is IV.15 of Euclid’s Elements not synthetic?

Comment: @RobinSparrow IV.15 constructs a hexagon.  The OP asks "Given that we can construct a hexagon, prove that connecting every other vertex gives an equilateral triangle."

Comment: My comment last night was off - I misread your question =)

Comment: But after rereading I think I am still missing something. Euclid provides a synthetic path to inscribe any triangle in any circle, culminating in IV.2 where it is accomplished. The constructs you link to essentially begin with that of I.1, construction of the equilateral triangle, and assume certain knowledge about trig. But Euclid has no trig. With I.1 you have equilateral, by I.5 we have equal bases imply equal angles so you have equiangular, and with IV.2 you have inscription of any (equiangular) triangle into any circle.

Comment: @RobinSparrow You're right.  Construct an equilateral triangle (I.1) and "copy" it into the circle (IV.2).  This actually involves more steps than the methods in the OP (esp. because IV.2 requires constructing a tangent), but the proof is an immediate consequence of the Elements' propositions you cite.  Would you consider writing this up as a proper answer? I think others would find it useful.

Comment: No problem, my longest post by miles =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euclid provides in book IV of Elements methods for inscribing in a given circle shapes of triangles, squares, pentagons, hexagons, and in general regular mn-gons where m and n are constructible regular polygons. Euclid is entirely synthetic and trig is involved only in the sense that right angles are defined axiomatically such that two of them form a straight line. I'll outline the main path to inscribing an equilateral triangle, and point out that other routes are possible.

The main road map: (1) construct an equilateral triangle; (2) prove that equilateral triangles are equiangular; (3) prove that equiangular triangles are equilateral; (4) construct an equiangular triangle in a given circle.

The proofs are general and apply to all triangles. And I'm not going to show or describe everything, just the highlights. In the images below, what is given is in red.

Step 1: Given any length (in red), use it as the radius of circles constructed at either end, then segments from the intersection of the circle to the centers have the same length, and we have an equilateral triangle.

[image]

Step 2: Equal sides imply equal angles. Given a triangle with equal sides, extend each side by a fixed length (//). Now, using mirror triangles in the triangle, by SAS we have two triangles with equal apex angles $\alpha$ and sides (/) and (/+//). Thus the diagonals under the base (///) are the same, as are angles marked $\beta$, as are the angles marked with the single arc. Further, again by SAS, the inferior mirror triangles composed of (//), $\beta$, and (///) are equal, meaning that the sections of the single-arc-angle under the original base (marked with double arcs) are equal. Hence the angles in the single-arc-angles above the base are equal. So equal sides in isosceles triangles imply equal base angles. This immediately implies an equilateral triangle is equiangular.

[image]

Step 3: Equal base angles imply equal sides. Given equal base angles, suppose for a contradiction that the sides were not equal. Whichever is larger, cut it down to equal the other, and connect it to the base (via the dotted line). Now, by SAS, the indicated triangles are equal, which is absurd. Therefore the sides must be equal. This implies an equiangular triangle is equilateral.

[image]

Step 4a: Prove that in a circle, an inscribed angle subtending an arc is half the central angle subtending the arc. Here, the angle in the middle is at the center of the circle. Draw the diameter from the inscribed angle through the center. Examining the triangles thus formed, we have an isosceles with sides the radius, thus equal base angles $\alpha$, and since exterior angles are the sum of opposite interior angles, the exterior angle on the diameter is $2\alpha$. And likewise for the triangles on the other side, so for an inscribed angle $\delta$, the central angle subtending the same arc has angle $2\delta$.

[image]

Step 4b: Prove that all inscribed angles subtending an arc are equal. Suppose two inscribed angles subtend the same arc. Draw the central angle subtending the arc, which is twice an inscribed angle on the same arc by (4a), hence the inscribed angles subtending the arc are the same.

[image]

Step 4c: In a circle, prove the angle between a tangent and a chord originating at the tangent is also the inscribed angle subtending the chord. Given the tangent and chord with angle $\delta$ between them, form the diameter at the point the tangent touches the circle. This diameter will be perpendicular to the tangent. Inscribed angles subtending a diameter are right angles. And since the angles of a triangle sum to two right angles, the angle subtending the chord is the angle $\delta$. And by (4b) any inscribed angle subtending that chord also has angle $\delta$.

[image]

Step 4d: Inscribe any triangle in any circle. Given a triangle and a circle, draw a tangent and form chords whose angles with the tangent are two of the angles of the triangle, here $\alpha$ and $\delta$. Connect the endpoints of the chords. By (4c), the enclosed angles are also $\alpha$, $\delta$ and the triangles are thus similar.

Step 5: The actual proof of inscribing an equilateral thus goes: construct an equilateral of any size. It is equiangular. "Copy" the equiangular triangle into the circle of interest. Equiangular triangles are equilateral. So you have inscribed an equilateral triangle in the circle.

[image]

Comment: I've obviously skipped some steps and proofs, I wanted to get across the gist, since you can read the entire chain of proofs in the original. Anyone can see that construction I.1 leads by repeated application to a regular hexagon inscribed in one of the circles. If you wished to use that construct purely, you need that the the sum of angles in a triangle are two right angles, and that if a set of neighboring angles sharing a vertex sum to two right angles, the outermost rays form a straight line. Such proofs are also in Book I of Elements. So you could use that route on the I.1 construct to prove an inscribed equilateral triangle. The proofs linked by the OP are based on Euclid I.1, using trig to skip some of these steps. If you are interested in synthetic geometry but haven't read Euclid's first 6 books, it can be found online and also Green Lion Press recently published a nice print version (that I have and like).

Comment: Well done! That's a new mode of a diagrams, sequentially building the proof.  I haven't seen that mode before (most diagrams are "single scene", all encompassing, much harder to follow).   Can you share any information or sources on this style?

Comment: Thanks! No source, it's just what I would want someone to show me if we couldn't share a chalkboard or paper. In person you would point out what's important or new at each step, and probably erase stuff that no longer matters and clutters as the proof develops. This is the closest I can get to that.

Answer (score 1):

Proving the first method:
Suppose that $ABC$ is a triangle in which $\angle ABC=90°$ and $AC=2BC$, let's called $C'$ the symmetric of $C$ with respect to $B$, then, by the properties of the simetry, $BC=BC'$ and $AC'=AC=2BC$, but $BC'=BC$, then $CC'=2BC=AC=AC'$ and $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle, so angle $\angle BCA$ must be equal to $60°$.

[image]

Now I'll prove the second one. Let $ABCDEF$ be the regular hexagon, by the simetry of the regular polygons the diagonals $AC$, $CE$, and $EA$ are all equals, because they all "skip a vertex" to the right, then the triangle $ACE$ is equilateral as desired.

If the simetry argument is not convencing enough, note that $AB=BC=CD=DE=EF=FA$ because the hexagon is regular. Note that the sum of the interior angles is $180 \times (6-2)=720$, then each angle is $120°$. Note that triangles $ABC$, $CDE$ and $EFA$ have $\angle ABC = \angle CDE = \angle EFA = 120°$ and $AB=BC=CD=DE=EF=FA$ so that the three triangles are equal to each other and $AC=CE=EA$ and the triangle $ACE$ is equilateral.

[image]

Comment: The gaven construction in the post works based on the fact that if you have a right triangle in which one of the sides is half of the hypotenuse, then it's got a $60°$ angle. I proved with synthetic geo that this fact is actually true, which is not obvious, I understood that the problem was to understand why is that true.

Comment: @BrianMoehring "If you reflect $C$ across $AB$, then its image $C′$  is outside the circle, not on it." True - but so what? We know [$\angle PBQ$ ](https://tasks.illustrativemathematics.org/content-standards/tasks/1557) is $60 \deg$, and we know by symmetry that the other two angles are equal.  Hence the triangle is equilateral.  What do you feel is missing?

Comment: @BrianMoehring No, we need to show that $\triangle PQB$ is equilateral.

Answer (score 0):

I will be referencing the diagram and vertex-labeling appearing in [the IM link](https://tasks.illustrativemathematics.org/content-standards/tasks/1557), but additionally call the left circle's center $C$.  The main difference is that I will be completely ignoring the 2:1 ratio in favor of an equilateral triangle we already have in the "usual" method 1.  In that sense, maybe I'm responding to 1' rather than 1.
*In case that link is dead, the setup is as follows: Given a circle with center $C$ and a point $B$ on the circle, let $\overline{AB}$ be the diameter containing $B$.  Then draw a second circle with center $A$ that goes through $C$, and call the circles' two intersection points $P$ and $Q$.*

---

Since $A,P$ lie on the first circle, $CA=CP$, and since $C,P$ lie on the second circle, $AC=AP$.  Together, this shows $\triangle ACP$ is equilateral, hence equiangular, so that $$\measuredangle BAP = \measuredangle CAP = 60^\circ.$$

Since $\overline{AB}$ is a diameter of a circle containing $P$, the angle $\angle APB$ is a right angle.  Therefore $\angle BAP, \angle ABP$ are complementary, so that $$\measuredangle ABP = 90^\circ - \measuredangle BAP = 30^\circ.$$

By a symmetric argument [replacing $P$ with $Q$], we find $\measuredangle ABQ = 30^\circ$.

Comment: Honestly, I don't like measuring angles in constructions, so I'd like to remove that, but it doesn't sound like that is necessary for your uses, and it would complicate things unnecessarily ("twice the complement of the angle $\alpha$ in an equiangular triangle is congruent to $\alpha$" by dropping a perpendicular and using congruence postulates isn't hard, but it is a bit of a sidetrack)

Comment: No problem with the usage of angle measure; it's an acceptable shorthand.  But the proof seems like it needs to be finished.  Which is the final inscribed equilateral triangle? If it's $\triangle PBQ$, you've shown $\angle PBQ = \angle ABP + \angle ABQ = 60 ^\circ$, but haven't shown either of the other two ($\angle PQB$ or $\angle BPQ$) are.

Comment: @SRobertJames Honestly, after you said the other answer sufficed, I'm a bit confused, as it didn't go even that far.  In short, the remaining proof would parallel what IM has, using congruence postulates to first show $BP=BQ$ and then (since it's an isosceles triangle) another congruence postulate to find the base angles are congruent.  I cannot recall if all the congruence postulates are trig-free, though

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the center of the circle? A new circle centered anywhere on the circle having the same radius will intersect the original circle at two points whose corresponding arc subtends and angle of 120 degrees. We know this because the given points can be used to form 2 equilateral triangles. The sum of adjacent angles of adjacent equilateral triangles is $120^\circ$.  Continue creating circles in this way and then connect every other intersection. You get an inscribed equilateral triangle.

Comment: "Do you know the center of the circle?" _Yes; if not, [it can be found](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII1.html)_.  "the original center and the two intersections are all equidistant from each other" _Are you sure? I think the original center, the **second circle's center**, and **one** of the intersection points are mutually equidistant; but the two intersection points are further apart_.  "...connect every other intersection. You get an inscribed equilateral triangle."  _This is Method 2 of the OP, which asks to **prove this**.  Have you done that?_